# How can I check if append element already exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
if (result.Indicator == 1) {
    $('#IndicatorImgDiv').append($('<img />').attr("src", "/Content/images/reddot.png"));
}
```

Now, this appends an image of a red dot when I click on a button but when I click on a button again, it appends it again. I just want it to appear once when I click on a button. How can I check if the appended element already exists or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do the next:

Html code

```
    <input id="addImage" type="button" value="Add image"/>
    <div id="IndicatorImgDiv">
    </div>
```

Javascript code

```
    $("#addImage").click(function(){
         if($("#IndicatorImgDiv img").length == 0){
             $('#IndicatorImgDiv').append($('<img />').attr("src", "http://www.thepointless.com/images/reddot.jpg"));
         }
    });
```

[Here the JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/osbm0rtn/2/)

Comment: Thank you, your solution ended up working the best for me! I just changed it the if statement to include this: ($("#IndicatorImgDiv img").length == 0

Comment: @WinnerCrespo You additionally might indicate that this is jQuery rather than Vanilla JS

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
$('#IndicatorImgDiv').append($('<img />').attr("src", "/Content/images/reddot.png"));
```

To:

```
$('#IndicatorImgDiv').find('img[src$="reddot.png"]').length ||
    $('#IndicatorImgDiv').append($('<img />').attr("src", "/Content/images/reddot.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
if($('img').length >= 1){
    alert('element exist');
}
```